# Angular CLI doesnt work so trying a reinstall but get this error

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am on version 6.12 and not sure if I need to uninstall something before running:

> npm install -g @angular/cli npm ERR! code ELOOP npm ERR! syscall stat
>   npm ERR! path \UserFS\AppData\ npm ERR! errno -62 npm ERR! ELOOP: too
>   many symbolic links encountered, stat '\UserFS\AppData\'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   \UserFS\AppData\mjones\Application
>   Data\npm-cache_logs\2020-03-23T17_04_01_197Z-debug.log

Here is the Log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   '@angular/cli'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.12.0
3 info using node@v12.13.0
4 verbose npm-session 2b78e4caf18e9e98
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli 270ms (from cache)
8 silly pacote tag manifest for @angular/cli@latest fetched in 322ms
9 verbose stack Error: ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, stat '\\UserFS\AppData\'
9 verbose stack     at eloop (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:58:17)
```

Comment: Ouch... try cleaning the npm cache or even deleting the global instance.  What does the log say?

Comment: Added the log and tried deleting the CLI and got the same error

Comment: At this point I would try a different version of NPM.